# The characteristic function of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

How can I use this formula of the characteristic function in a discrete set: $$\phi_X(t)=\sum \exp(itx_k)P(X=x_k)$$

To prove that the characteristic function is defined, uniformly continuous and that the transformation $Y=aX+b$
gives $\phi_Y(t)=\exp(ibt)\cdot\phi_X(at)$ without the use of $E[e^{itx}]$ in the proof?

I can only find proofs online using $E[eitx]$ or proofs in a continuous set.

Comment: Do I save the same expression of the probability as P(X=xk) for the characteristic function of Y, or do I do P( (Y-b)/a= (yk-b)/a), because if I do the latter, I dont undrestand how can I obtain P(Y=yk)

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math here.

Comment: I have erased my (too complicated) comment and given instead a detailed answer

Comment: @browneyedwanderer In the future, please don't edit/delete your question when you get an answer. It is helpful to future readers googling the same question if it stays here.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting by $y_k$ the value taken by $Y$ when $X$ takes the value $x_k$ (therefore $P(Y=y_k)=P(X=x_k)$):

$$\Phi_Y(t)=\sum e^{ity_k}P(Y=y_k)=\sum e^{it(ax_k+b)}P(X=x_k)$$

$$\Phi_Y(t)=\sum e^{i(at)x_k}e^{itb}P(X=x_k)$$

$$\Phi_Y(t)=e^{itb}\underbrace{\sum e^{itax_k}P(X=x_k)}_{\Phi_X(at)}$$

Comment: I tried this proof before but I couldnt figure out why do the two probabilities of X and Y equal eachother so I always assumed it was wrong

Comment: Yes indeed, if for example $x_1=3$ and the rule is $Y=10X+1$, $y_1=31$ and $P(X=x_1)=P(Y=y_1)$

Comment: Yes , I can somewhat see it now, thank you a lot for your help

Comment: Also, when it comes to the characteristic function being uniformly continuous, can we use the fact that exp(itxk)P(X=xk) is bounded by 1 therefore convergent, and then prove the normal convergence and say that it is uniformly continuous (i apologize i am not used to MathJax)

Comment: Two things 1) "therefore convergent" : I don't understand why you are speaking about convergence. 2)About general uniform continuity (here we have a particular case) see this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108673

Comment: Yes, the thing is in the example you gave me, we use the dominated convergence theorem since we have integrals, however when it comes to the discrete variables case, we need to prove that it is normally convergent and then deduce that is it uniformly convergent, but i'm not sure how to apply the previous example in my case

Comment: i'll try real quick to use MathJax to show you where I got blocked

Comment: I will be away for a while now. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and here's what i was trying to explain earlier https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3813464/821665