# How to prove that the characteristic function is uniformly continuous in a discrete set.

Tags: probability

Proving the uniform continuity of a characteristic function using only the formula $$\phi_X(t)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{itx_k}P(X=x_k)$$

So all I got so far is $$|\phi(s)-\phi(t)|$$ $$<\sum_{k=0}^\infty |(e^{isx_k} - e^{itx_k})P(X=x_k)|$$given that h=s-t;$$|\phi(s) - \phi(t)|$$
$$<\sum_{k=0}^\infty |(e^{i(t+h)x_k} -e^{itx_k})P(X=x_k)|$$
But then while using the limit as h -> 0 I don’t know how to finish it. I heard that we need to apply normal convergence since we don’t work with integrals but I don’t undrestand how this helps with proving that the function is uniformly continuous!

Comment: Suggest you roll back the title to what it was, so your question can be more easily found by future searchers.

Comment: Also suggest changing the question tags; the (logic) tag does not seem appropriate. Better tags will make your question easier to find.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exist $N$ such that $  \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} P(X=k) <\frac {\epsilon} 4$. Also $|e^{ix}-e^{iy}| \leq |x-y|$ for any real numbers $x$ and $y$. Hence $|\phi(s)-\phi (t) | \leq \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} P(X=k)|itx_k-isx_k| +\epsilon/2$. Let $\delta =\frac {\epsilon} {2 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} P(X=k)|x_k|}$. Then $|\phi(s)-\phi (t) | <\epsilon$ for $|t-s| <\delta$.

Comment: Le me know if more details are needed. @browneyewanderer

Comment: Is there also another way where we can use the normal convergence method to deduce that it is uniformly convergent?

Comment: Saying that $f(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ is same as saying that you can make $|f(h)| <\epsilon$ by taking $|h|$ less than some $\delta$. In what way is my argument different from your approach ?

Comment: Thank you a lot, would you mind elaborate on \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} P(X=k) <\frac {\epsilon} 4$ like why did we work with k from N+1 towards infinity in here but then used k=0 towards N on the second line of the demonstration

Comment: I am splitting the sum into two parts: sum from $0$ to $N$ and sum from $N+1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I think this is the best proof I came across so far but I do have some troubles undrestanding the choice of and δ and ϵ

Comment: The idea is to make the second term small by choosing  and fixing one large $N$. And then you are left with a finite sum. The choice of $\delta$ is now obvious from the fact that you want to make the first term small.

Comment: The sum of the probabilities is <1. You bounded the sum of the probabilities by ϵ/4, however we know ϵ -> 0, so does this always apply

Comment: If $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n <\infty$ the $ \sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ This is a basic fact from Calculus.

Comment: Okay I see, what about this one $\delta =\frac {\epsilon} {2 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} P(X=k)|x_k|}$. , does $$|x_k|$$ stand for $$|isx_k - itx_k|$$, I apologize for the excessive questions

Comment: $|isx_k-itx_k|=|t-s| |x_k|$.

Comment: I got it, thank you. Also, to prove the existence of this function,  can we say that is it bounded by 1 therefore it is convergent, and thus exists?